# Attach an event to typeahead

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead

Here is my code an it works fine except the event code, What is wrong with selected call back in this code?

```
 $('#phone_input').typeahead({                                
    name: 'contact',                                                          
    local: contacts,   
    limit: 10 ,   
    template: '<p>{{tokens.0}}</p>',   
    engine: Hogan ,                                                           
    selected: function(n,data) { 
       console.log(data) ;
    }
});
```

Comment: What's wrong with it?

Comment: It doesn't work! I'm guessing it should trigger selected when an item is selected, right?